# Count field Pivot table In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have this table - Name : Mytable:

```
         Amount  Desc    Month   Sym  code    ID
        $32,323.00  Bla1    1   121 3   2424221
        $4,242.00   Bla1    1   121 3   2424221
        $3,535.00   Bla1    1   121 1   3230824
        $4,984.00   Bla2    1   433 1   3230824
        $47,984.00  Bla2    2   433 1   3230824
        $41.00      Bla2    2   433 1   3230824
        $3,472.00   Bla6    1   D2  27  2297429
        $3,472.00   Bla6    1   D2  27  2297429
        $3,239.00   Bla6    2   D2  27  2297429
        $4,249.00   Bla8    2   114 24  3434334
```

ID and Month  Stands for for a paycheck. There are 6 paychecks : 1 + 3230824, 2+3230824 etc.

And I want to generate a pivot like this:

```
       Jan                Feb
     count amount   count amount
121    2    40100$     0    0
433    1    52968$     1   48025$
D2     1    6944$      1   3239$
114    0     0         1   4249$
```

Explanation: 121 is two in Jan because ID = 2424221 got it twice and 3230824 got it one time. The number of of "occurrences" in the paychecks is two.

But, In the amount I  sum every thing To get the total sum of money in the paycheck for that Sym.

Same, 433 got the value of 1 in Feb for example because only 3230824 got it (twice).

I started writing this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Sym] as Sym, [Month] as [month], [Amount] as Amount 
    FROM Mytable
) as T
PIVOT
(
    Sum(Amount)
    FOR [Month] IN ([1],[2])
)AS piv
```

Well, The amounts are correct But I  don't know how can I pull this count as I explained near the amount in the pivot table.

Comment: `433` has only one entry for Month 1 for `$4,984.00`  where do you come up with `52968$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    [Sym],
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN [1] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [Cnt] END), 0) [Jan Count], 
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN [1] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [1] END), 0) [Jan Amount],
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN [2] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [Cnt] END), 0) [Feb Count],
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN [2] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [2] END), 0) [Feb Amount]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        mt1.[Sym] as Sym, mt1.[Month] as [month], mt1.[Amount] as Amount, mt2.[Cnt]
    FROM Mytable mt1
    JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [ID]) [Cnt], [Sym], [Month] 
            FROM MyTable 
            GROUP BY [Sym], [Month]) mt2 
        ON mt1.[Sym] = mt2.[Sym] AND mt1.[Month] = mt2.[Month] 

) as T
PIVOT
(
    Sum(Amount)
    FOR [Month] IN ([1],[2])
)AS piv
GROUP BY [Sym]
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bf04/1)

Comment: Thank's. 
The Amount are correct but seems like the sml value take's on values that are not in the original data. Any Reason for that?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you're asking.. what is sml value?

Comment: sorry. 
Whell I mad a trim to the values and it worked.

Comment: sorry. 
WelI mad a trim to the values and it worked. Thank you.

But if I want that the pivot will only run on data that have code 1 and 3 ? (See My table) , where to add the "where"?

Comment: in the same query where you do `SELECT FROM MyTable`

Comment: Hey,
If I want to add the grand total(not the distinct) where to add it?